# SharePoint 2013 workflow and User Profile Service

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

This is another question about SharePoint 2013 workflows and the use of the User Profile Service.

At this moment, I've developed some workflows which function properly. However I've been trying to get the User Profile Service disabled, because I don't need it. After reading a lot of topics, I'm aware that the UPS is used by the Workflow Manager, and thus disabling the UPS will break the workflows; authentication errors are thrown when trying to execute a workflow.

[image]

I was wondering if it possible to disable this authentication, and thus to be able to run a SharePoint 2013 workflow without having the UPS enabled. I'm asking this because we can't sync User Profiles with our AD, as we aren't granted the permission to replicate from the AD. This causes to have blank User Profiles.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score -1):

Having the User Profile Service enabled doesn't mean that user profiles will be sync'd from Active Directory. User Profile Service and User Profile Synchronisation service are two different services.

Sync will occur only if you enable the sync service, configure the sync by configuring the connection etc.

Comment: My question is to have the UPS disabled completely, as I can't sync User Profiles because of permissions which can't be granted.

Comment: I think that's what i mentioned. Because you can't sync, just disable the sync. Why disable the User Profile Service? They are two different services - Central Admin --> Manage Services on Server